# Traveling Southeast Asia - Cambodia, Thailand, Malaysia - Visa Questions

Tags: thailand, malaysia, southeast-asia, e-visas, cambodia

I am planning a trip in December to Cambodia, Thailand and Malaysia. My initial plan is as follows;

- Karachi -> Cambodia (by air)
- Cambodia -> Thailand (by bus)
- Thailand -> Malaysia (by ferry)

I have a few questions around that, would be super helpful if someone can answer these.
I know many of you have already done that.

- How was your experience in terms of getting visas, booking tickets and traveling?
- Can we get Cambodia & Malaysia e-visa on dummy tickets? It means I can book tickets through any airline for 24 hrs without paying and attach a copy? Is this right do to so?
- For Thailand visa, is it necessary to book through Thai Airways? If yes, how can I apply visa for Thailand in my case (where I won't be entering and leaving Thailand by air)?
- At Cambodian and Thai immigration, would it be okay if I show them bus and ferry bookings along with flight?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you intent to travel by bus or ferry and can buy tickets in advance, use those instead of dummy (actually fake) bookings.

Comment: I presume you are a Pakistani national?

Comment: @Willeke I intended to ask the same if they can give visas on bus and ferry tickets?

Comment: @lambshaanxy yes I am.

Answer (score 1):

As for the Cambodian eVisa, you don't need to provide a flight booking, only a hotel reservation, and the port of entry – which isn't necessarily an airport: I've entered Cambodia in Poipet for instance. So no flight required makes sense.

[image: Cambodia eVisa page]

On the other hand, the Thai eVoA can only applied for if you fly in. If you don't want to fly to Thailand, you'll have to get a visa at the Thai Consulate... I suggest you revise your plan, and land in Thailand first, then bus to Poipet and onwards: as I said above the Cambodian eVisa doesn't require a flight.

**UPDATE:** On second thought, I seem to remember land borders that issued VoA on site, including Poipet. That could be a solution, but it means you wouldn't be able to apply in advance, but get it on arrival – with a wait time of possibly several hours.

[image]

No idea for the Malaysian eVisa, someone else can fill in.